# Magento 2.2.8 and 3D Secure v2 (SCA / PSD2)

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-express, magento2.2.8, psd2

Come 14th September 3D Secure v2 comes into effect. (Some places call it Strong Customer Authentication or Payment Services Directive 2)

Does anyone know if your the native Paypal integration (PayPal Express Checkout) is fully compatible and if any updates will need to be applied to ensure we can still take payments with 3D Secure V2?

Paypal have "[It pays to be prepared for PSD2](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/psd2)" but it does not mention how to check if your version of Magento is covered

Along with this Paypal state the following:

> PayPal Pro hosted
>   With our hosted solution, when a customer pays, a payment page either opens in a separate frame or the customer is redirected. If you use our hosted solution, then we manage your payment process at checkout. We will automatically upgrade the payment process, so you don’t need to worry. But, if you want to know more, visit our PSD2 page.

This was taken from [here](https://www.paypal.com/uk/brc/article/psd2-payment-requirements-make-sure-you-are-ready) however this relates to "PayPal Pro hosted" and not PayPal Express

Comment: We don't use paypal express, but does it redirect to paypal for payment?  if so i think it will be ok.  I'm basing this on sagepay form and server methods will be ok, but if you are using sagepay direct, then you will need to update.

Answer (score 0):

Magento sent a [newsletter](http://email2.magento.com/gh0n5qX0c20NGD0sG000RZk) today with the following Magento Commerce 2.x PayPal recommendation:

> Continue using the current Magento built-in integration, as the 3D Secure 2.0 payment flow changes are all handled by PayPal.

I'm wondering why the Magento Commerce 1.x (and Magento 1 Open Spource?) PayPal recommendation differs, though:

> 3DS 1.0 is supported. When and/or where use of 3DS 2.0 is required, Merchants will either need to replace PayPal with Braintree or upgrade to Magento 2.3.x.

I reached out to Piotr Kaminski, who is a Lead Product Manager at Magento and he replied as follows:

> The PayPal integration that is in 1.x for some of the PayPal payment methods require use of Cardinal for 3D secure. The Cardinal integration only supports 3DS 1.0. PayPal Standard/Express/HSS Pro is not affected. All the others (PayFlow Pro, PayFlow Link, PP Payments Pro 2.0/3.0, PP Advanced) are affected and the recommendation is to switch to Braintree.